# datatables.columnfilter plugin filter from External Form

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to filter via external form in datatables.
The table appears but no filter boxes. I have done exactly what it says in these examples: [example 1](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/source/browse/trunk/external.html?r=52) and [example 2](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/external.html)

Does anybody have any ideas where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Also I am trying to populate the values for the select filter from a db table, I have included my code below, can anybody see anything wrong with this as this is also not working.

**my form and datatable**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="display" id="Table1">
    <tbody>
       <tr id="filter_global">
           <td align="center">Employee</td>
           <td align="center" id="employee"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="filter_col1">
           <td align="center">Division</td>
           <td align="center" id="division"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="filter_col2">
           <td align="center">Line manager</td>
           <td align="center" id="line_manager"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="filter_col3">
           <td align="center">Contract</td>
           <td align="center" id="contract"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="filter_col4">
           <td align="center">Entitlement</td>
           <td align="center" id="entitlement"></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class="dataTable" id="academic_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Year</th> 
<th>Employee</th>  
<th>Division</th>
<th>Line Manager</th>
<th>Contract</th>
<th>Entitlement</th>
<th>Units</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Year</th> 
<th>Employee</th>  
<th>Division</th>
<th>Line Manager</th>
<th>Contract</th>
<th>Entitlement</th>
<th>Units</th>
</tr> 
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

**db for select values**

```
$line_managers_filter = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM line_managers");
$division_filter = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM divisions");
```

**Initialise datatables column filter etc..**

```
   var $acTable= $("#academic_table").dataTable( {
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Filter:"
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "scripts/academic_serverside.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,       
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
            "sDom": '<"clear"><"top"CTilr<"clear">pt>',
            "aoColumns": [ 
                {"bVisible":false},
                {"bVisible":true},
                {"bVisible":true},
                {"bVisible":true},
                {"bVisible":true},
                {"bVisible":true},
                {"bVisible":false}
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html(''+ aData[5] +'&nbsp;'+ aData[6] +'');
            },
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "oColVis": {
                "activate": "mouseover",    
                "aiExclude": [0,6]
            }
        }).columnFilter({   
                aoColumns: [ 
                        { type: "select"},
                        { type: "text", sSelector: "#employee" },
                        { type: "select", values : [<?php 
                                                $tmp = Array();
                                                foreach($division_filter as $row) $tmp[] = '{value: "'.$row['name'].'"}'; 
                                                    echo join(',', $tmp);
                                                    ?>], 
                          sSelector: "#division" },
                        { type: "select", values : [<?php 
                                                $tmp = Array();
                                                    foreach($line_managers_filter as $row) $tmp[] = '{value: "'.$row['name'].'"}'; 
                                                    echo join(',', $tmp);
                                                    ?>], 
                        sSelector: "#line_manager"},
                        { type: "select", values : ["A", "B", "C"], sSelector: "#contract"},
                        { type: "text", sSelector: "#entitlement"},
                        { type: "text"}
                    ]
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that "**jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js**" has version **1.5**, or higher.

Answer (score 2):

you missing sPlaceHolder: **"head:before"**

```
.columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [
                    { sSelector: "#filter #column1" }
                ]
```